# how to: make a panel resize with its form; and attach a console for output

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console

1. how to make the Panel widget change it's size on Form1_SizeChanged
2. how to attach a console window in order to see console.writeline messages

Comment: This is two seperate questions...you should split and ask each seperately.

Comment: You should also come up with a more descriptive title than "simple .NET question".

Comment: @Kyralessa: "two simple .NET questions" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To resize a control when the parent control size changed you can use the [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property.
2. To get a console window for a WinForms application just go to *Project Properties* and change *Output type* in the *Application* tab from *Windows Application* to *Console Application*.

Answer (score 4):

1. Take a look at the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties on the panel. These let the panel change its size along with the form; you won't need to write any code.
2. It's a little tricky to [attach a console to a running app](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AllocConsole.html). If you're just interested in seeing debug messages, look at the Visual Studio output window, or call `Debug.WriteLine` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to get your Panel to resize is to Anchor or Dock it into the form. Play with the properties pane a bit and you should see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Anchor` or `Dock` properties. To see the console window in Visual Studio go to the menu *View* and there you should check displaying "Output".